# How can i calculate mask of a specific subnet in a list of subnets knowing only the supernet address

Tags: ip, ip-address, subnet

**1.** I have these subnets :

```
subnet 1 = 9.68.2.0/24
subnet 2 = 9.68.3.0/25
subnet 3 = 9.68.3.128/???
```

and I am supposed to get the supernet and also the submask of the last subnet "**???**".
I calculated the supernet and the supernet mask and I got this :

`9.68.2.0/23`

My problem is that I don't know how can I calculate the subnet mask of 9.68.3.128 only with these information.

Binary interpretation :

```
9.68.00000010.00000000 /24 (subnet1)
9.68.00000011.00000000 /25 (subnet2)
9.68.00000011.10000000 /??? (subnet3)
=
9.68.00000010.00000000 /23 (supernet)
```

**2.** Same problem with this example but with only two subnets :

```
subnet 1 = 112.110.0.0/16
subnet 2 = 112.111.0.0/???
```

I got the supernet :

`112.110.0.0 / 15`

but then again I don't know how to get the submask of the second subnet.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can calculate subnet 3's mask/prefix length with the information provided.

It can be anything from 25 (the minimum number of bits needed to express `9.68.3.128`) up to 32.